# Filtering polymorphic association by type for a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association that looks like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eventable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

With a bunch of types:

```
class Nap < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Eventable
end

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Eventable
end

module Eventable
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      has_one :event, :as => :eventable, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :event, :allow_destroy => true

      scope :happened_at, -> (date) {
        where("events.happened_at >= ? AND events.happened_at <= ?",
        date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day).order("events.happened_at ASC")
      }

      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    define_method(:today) do
      self.happened_at(Date.today)
    end
  end
end
```

And so on.

Here's the other end of the relationship:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  has_many :meals, {
    :through => :events,
    :source => :eventable,
    :source_type => "Meal"
  }
  has_many :naps, {
    :through => :events,
    :source => :eventable,
    :source_type => "Nap"
  }
  has_many :moods, {
    :through => :events,
    :source => :eventable,
    :source_type => "Mood"
  }
  has_many :notes, {
    :through => :events,
    :source => :eventable,
    :source_type => "Note"
  }
  ...
end
```

I want to grab all the events of all types that belong to a person for display in a single view. Here's what I'm doing:

```
def show
  @events = Event.by_person(@person).happened_at(date)

  @meals, @naps, @moods, @notes = [], [], [], [], []
  @events.each do |e|
    @meals << e.eventable if e.eventable_type == 'Meal'
    @naps << e.eventable if e.eventable_type == 'Nap'
    @moods << e.eventable if e.eventable_type == 'Mood'
    @notes << e.eventable if e.eventable_type == 'Note'
  end
end
```

I need to filter by type because the view is going to be displaying type-specific attributes in each section of the view.

**Question:** Should this logic of filtering out the collection of `events` by type into their own type-specific arrays exist in the controller? Or elsewhere? Perhaps the model?

I was reluctant to just pass `@events` to the view and have the type test happen in the view itself. That seemed wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if you might be doing something strange in the model layer. Could you add the relevant excerpts of `Eventable` and `Person`? I'm not entirely sure of the associations between these.

Comment: Also, do you think of meals, naps, moods and notes as being _events_? Or is there something more to the separation between `Event` and `Eventable`?

Comment: Can you please show whats written in Eventable...

Comment: @lime @vamsi-krishna Added the `Eventable` and `Person` code so it should be easier to understand. I'm not doing anything special in there, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@events` query to create a subquery without having to iterate (I'm assuming you have the inverse `has_many :events, as: :eventable` in each of your other models):

```
@events = Event.by_person(@person).happened_at(date)

@meals = Meal.joins(:event).where events: { id: @events }
@naps  =  Nap.joins(:event).where events: { id: @events }

# etc.
```

Comment: wow, that's much more concise than my code. Not sure about the efficiency of `group_by` vs. what I was doing, but that's not a concern right now. Q: would you factor that into a method on `Event` if it were going to be used from multiple controllers?

Comment: Also, note that in your example, `@eventables` is actually a hash of `Events` --i.e., you can't access the specific type properties until you do something like: `@eventables["Meal"][0].eventable.food`

Comment: You're very correct, I'm sorry, I came at this too quickly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think it needs to be `@meals = Meal.joins(:event).where events: { id: @events }` (singular `:event`). Otherwise, good to go! But to go back to my main question--should this gathering logic be **in the controller** or elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry yes, as I said I was assuming a `has_many` but I see you've updated your question to show it's a `has_one`. And yes, it's fine to put this in the controller.

Comment: I ended up using `includes` instead of `join` because it performs fewer queries. thanks again!